# add custom field to New Event

Tags: picklist, fields, event

I would like to change the Subject field to a picklist with specific values.

I am unable to identify where I can do this within Setup - can anyone please advise?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It's a freeform text with a dropdown of suggestions. In setup, it is already a Picklist type, but rendered as a search-type lookup.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox . So the fields and layout within 'New Event' cannot be customized?

Comment: @h3110 The layouts can be altered almost any way you like, but most standard fields (aside from picklist values) can't really be customized.

Comment: thanks! I understand layouts can be customized, but the one in my image about, can this be customized? I'm unsure where to find this layout within setup.

Comment: @h3110 You can go to Setup > Object Manager > Events > Compact Layouts to configure the displayed fields and order in this component.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox